# How can I solve an problem with two select statements in one query

Tags: php, sql, database, tags, meta

I want to retrieve `og` tags with `sql` in `php` language but I only get to see 1 result, that is the first one he reads, the other I don't get to see in page source.

this is the **code** with `php`.

```
$query = "SELECT metatitle FROM isacontent_content WHERE contentid = 12245
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT name FROM isacontent_module_anchorimage WHERE contentid = 12245";

$resimage = $conn->query($query);

if(is_array($resimage)){

    foreach ($resimage as $resItem){

        $metaData[] = $resItem->fetch_assoc();

    }

}else{

    $metaData[] = $resimage->fetch_assoc();

}
$title = $metaData[0]["metatitle"];   
$image = $metaData[0]["name"];
```

I expect that both select statements will work and I can see both contents in the meta tags

Comment: column name must be same. i think

Comment: yes column name must be same you can set another flag whether it is from content of achor image.

Comment: for example `SELECT metatitle as name,  'content' as flag FROM isacontent_content WHERE contentid = 12245
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT name, 'anchor' as flag FROM isacontent_module_anchorimage WHERE contentid = 12245`

Comment: or you can simply use join

Comment: I dont see the reason why anyone should downvote this. The moderators should take a look at such trigger-happy members who discourage new contributors.

Comment: for example `SELECT isacontent_content.metatitle, isacontent_module_anchorimage.name  FROM isacontent_content join isacontent_module_anchorimage on isacontent_module_anchorimage.contentid =  isacontent_content.contentid WHERE isacontent_content.contentid = 12245`

Comment: Hmmm...seems  like my comment had an effect. Whoever downvoted this  seems  to have removed his downvote :)

Comment: after using join you can use this code `$title = $metaData[0]["metatitle"];   
$image = $metaData[0]["name"];`

Comment: @raidenace: no its not OP got upvote :) your comment didnt effect

Comment: @devpro aah good :) then the moderators can still take a look..

Comment: @raidenace: but issue is that, OP got three answers, but no one notice including OP yet. :)

Comment: did u checked the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), your column name must be same or you can use [`ALIAS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for this.

but, here in your example, you can simply use `INNER JOIN` to get the both values from 2 tables by using 1 single query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT ic.metatitle, im.name FROM isacontent_content ic
INNER JOIN isacontent_module_anchorimage im ON im.contentid = ic.contentid
WHERE ic.contentid = 12245
```

Using [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) because your both tables having relation, so you can simply use `INNER JOIN`

**Side Note:**

If you know, your query will return 1 row then why are you storing data into an array here `$metaData[]`? you can simply store `$title` and `$image` inside you `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you use union, your columns have to be in same number as it will combine results of two queries. In your case your asking for an particular content results which are stored in multiple tables, so you can go for joins.